# GROUP BY not grouping DATE_FORMAT change in SELECT

Tags: mysql

I cannot seem to get my GROUP BY to handle Date correctly. Currently it is still grouping as if I used '%m/%e/%Y' in DATE_FORMAT.

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(Invoice.Date, '%m/%e/%Y'), '%m-%Y') AS Date,
SUM(Invoice.Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM Invoice
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Invoice.Date, '%m/%e/%Y') BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR) AND NOW()
GROUP BY Date
ORDER BY Date
```

Current output (as you can see, it shows multiples for each month because it somehow still sees the %e part):

```
01-2016 | 24017
01-2016 | 28886
01-2016 | 0
01-2016 | 31653
01-2016 | 18521
01-2017 | 29409
01-2017 | 23370
01-2017 | 37611
01-2017 | 14535
02-2016 | 16365
02-2016 | 27930
```

Expected Output:

```
01-2016 | 103077
01-2017 | 123446
02-2016 | 44295
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You the same expression in `group by`:

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(Invoice.Date, '%m/%e/%Y'), '%m-%Y') AS Date,
SUM(Invoice.Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM Invoice
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Invoice.Date, '%m/%e/%Y') BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR) AND NOW()
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(Invoice.Date, '%m/%e/%Y'), '%m-%Y')
ORDER BY Date
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the name `Date` is ambiguous in your query. It's best to use unique, descriptive names for your column aliases so they don't collide with the existing column names.

If you change your column alias to something like `date_month` then your query should work as expected:

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(Invoice.Date, '%m/%e/%Y'), '%m-%Y') AS date_month,
SUM(Invoice.Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM Invoice
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Invoice.Date, '%m/%e/%Y') BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR) AND NOW()
GROUP BY date_month
ORDER BY date_month
```